# Using CONVERT to check for specific day, results in conversion failed if day does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I am writing a query to calculate some time between certain user events, and for this I need to run an aggregate query for set days for an event. An event can run on multiple days, and for the data I am using to validate my query, there is data for Feb 27th, Feb 28th, but the event goes from Feb 25th - March 1st.

I am only using a subset of the data to validate the query, there will be a lot more data which matches more days, or less days.

So I am trying to add an IF check to my query to only run the aggregate if data exists for that specific day, like so:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sourcedata SD 
          JOIN @dwellTime DT ON SD.badgeid = DT.badgeid 
          WHERE SD.eventid = 1234 
          AND CONVERT(date, SD.DateAdded, 110) = '2018-02-29')
```

But as I say, my @dwellTime data does not have data for 29th, and when it tries to do the convert, no data is there to convert and I receive the

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

error.

How can I check for a specific day being in the data?

DateAdded is a datetime column.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If 2012+ use try_convert().  this will return a NULL for any conversion failures and NOT throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that "2018-02-29" is not a valid date.  This year, February had only 28 days.  The next leap year is 2020.

So, if you use a valid date for the comparison, you shouldn't have a problem.

If you want to include invalid dates, then you can make the comparison as a string rather than a date.  Or, you can use `try_convert(date, '2018-02-29')`.  This will return `NULL`.

Comment: How did I miss this? Thanks